# Get Distributionlist by GUID

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I'm have to get a Exchange `Distributionlist` by using powershell. The only thing I know about the list is the `GUID`.
So I've tried following:

```
function GroupGetName([string]$ADGuid)
{
$DISGR = Get-DistributionGroup -filter { Guid -like $ADGuid}
$DISGR
}
```

But it does not work (I think "Guid" is a internal name from powershell)

Does any one know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-DistributionGroup $ADGuid` should be sufficient. Per the docs (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124755.aspx), the objectGuid is a valid input for the `Identity` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try the -match operator instead of -like. If you pass a partial string to -like, it will expect wildcards to fill in the rest.

```
'asdf' -like 'a' # result: false
'asdf' -match 'a' # result: true
```

To test, run Get-DistributionGroup without the -Filter, and examine the GUID property on one of the returned objects. This should give you an idea of what you're looking for in the property's value.